# Counting products associated with hierarchical category listing

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

**What I have:**

A table of categories listed Hierarchically:
[image: category table]

A table of products. the column `category_id` refers to `category.id`:
[image]

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to design a query that will count products of catogries withing specified `lft` and `rgt` values.
for example: between `lft` = `2` and `rgt` = `11` there are 3 "Immediate subcategories" whose IDs are `3`, `4` and `5`. See that `wireless` subcategory is not included as it is not an immediate subcategory within the range of `lft` and `rgt` but the products of this subcategory will be counted as part of its immediate subcategory which is `headphone` as you can see from the picture below. `Headphone` has one direct product and another product relates to its `wireless` subcategory.

the result should be:

[image]

I have managed to make a query that retrieves immediate sub-categories within specified `lft` and `rgt` values.

```
    SELECT node.name,node.id, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
    FROM category AS node,
        category AS parent
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
        AND parent.lft BETWEEN {$lft} AND {$rgt}
    GROUP BY node.name
    HAVING depth = 1
    ORDER BY node.lft
```

This query will retrieve the sub-catogries like in the last picture when `lft` = `2` and `rgt` = `11` but it is missing the count.

I have experimenting to get that table of results right for quite a while and this is what I came up with but unfortunately it does not work well for some reason I do not know. I appreciate any help regarding this.

```
            SELECT parent.name, COUNT(product.category_id)
    FROM category AS node1 ,
            product, (
                SELECT node.name,node.id,node.lft,node.rgt, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
                FROM category AS node,
                    category AS parent
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                    AND parent.lft BETWEEN {$lft} AND {$rgt}
                GROUP BY node.name
                HAVING depth = 1
                ORDER BY node.lft
            ) as parent
    WHERE node1.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
            AND node1.id = product.category_id
    GROUP BY parent.lft
    ORDER BY parent.lft
```

**UPDATE:** I tried to make SQL fiddle but I got huge list of errors:

```
    CREATE TABLE category 
        (
         id int auto_increment primary key, 
         name varchar(20), 
         lft varchar(20),
          rgt varchar(20)
        );

    INSERT INTO category
    (name, lft,rgt)
    VALUES
    ('ELECTRONICS','1','18'),
    ('TV & audio','2','11'),
    ('Home theater','3','4'),
    ('Blu-ray','5','6'),
    ('Headphone','7','10'),
    ('Wireless','8','9'),
    ('Gaming','12','17'),
    ('Game consoles','13','14'),
    ('Video games','15','16');

    CREATE TABLE product 
        (
         id int auto_increment primary key, 
         name varchar(20), 
         category_id varchar(20)
        );
    INSERT INTO product
    (category_id, name)
    VALUES
    ('4','Sony Blu-ray player'),
    ('5','Beats Solo HD'),
    ('6','Beats Solo HD wireless'),
    ('8','PlayStation'),
    ('8','Xbox');
```

Comment: Can you make an sqlfiddle example

Comment: sqlfiddle is out of order at least for mysql currently

Comment: Can you explain why wireless will not qualify in your criteria (2 and 11), I am sorry if I am missing something simple

Comment: I am targeting the immediate subcategories (as sc1) within lft rgt range. All products related to sc1 will be counted whether they are directly linked to these sc1 or linked to thier subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be so simple (?) than something like:

```
SELECT category.name, COALESCE(C.total,0) as products
  FROM category 
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT category_id, count(*) as total FROM product GROUP BY category_id) AS C
  ON C.category_id = category.id
  WHERE category.lft > @min_range AND category.rgt < @max_range
```

If you ignore the "noise", this is just a left join (to keep categories *without* products) between the category table, and the count of products for each category.

Using your test case, it produces:

```
+--------------+----------+
| name         | products |
+--------------+----------+
| Home theater |        0 |
| Blu-ray      |        1 |
| Headphone    |        1 |
| Wireless     |        1 |
+--------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you see, it produces a result for *wireless* which does not appears in your *expected* result, but according to my understanding of your description of the problem, it *should* be there.

Comment: Headphone category has 2 products. One belongs to headphone category and one belongs to wireless subcategory

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi I was almost certain that couldn't be so simple! But maybe you should edit your question to clearly explain that "subcategory"-thing and how are "grouped" categories. It is not clear to me. And according to the comments and the lack of other answers, I'm not probably the only one in that case ;)

Comment: I am sorry for this.  I updated the description of my question. I hope it is clear now.